# Captured audio buffers are all silent on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, wasapi, windows-phone-voip

I'm trying to capture audio using WASAPI. My code is largely based on the [ChatterBox VoIP sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b). I'm getting audio buffers, but they are all silent (flagged AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT).

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone. Running on the emulator.

Comment: Are you sure that your microphone is actually available in the emulator? But I must recommend using a device for testing VoIP on Windows Phone!

Comment: Since the post I tried it on a phone. The problem happens there too.
The microphone works on the emulator. I managed to record audio use the XNA API.
At one point I also tried the [AudioVideoCaptureDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.audiovideocapturedevice.openforaudioonlyasync(v=vs.105).aspx) API and got the same issue - the buffers were all zeros.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem and managed to reproduce it in the ChatterBox sample app if I set Visual Studio to native debugging and at any point stepped through the code.

Also, closing the App without going through the "Stop" procedure and stopping the AudioClient will require you to restart the emulator/device before being able to capture audio data again.

It nearly drove me nuts before I figured out the before mentioned problems but I finally got it working.

So.. 
1. Be sure to NOT do native debugging
2. Always call IAudioClient->Stop(); before terminating the App. 
3. Make sure you pass the correct parameters to IAudioClient->Initialize();

I've included a piece of code that works 100% of the time for me. I've left out error checking for clarity..

```c
LPCWSTR pwstrDefaultCaptureDeviceId =
  GetDefaultAudioCaptureId(AudioDeviceRole::Communications);
HRESULT hr = ActivateAudioInterface(pwstrDefaultCaptureDeviceId,
  __uuidof(IAudioClient2), (void**)&m_pAudioClient);
hr = m_pAudioClient->GetMixFormat(&m_pwfx);
m_frameSizeInBytes = (m_pwfx->wBitsPerSample / 8) * m_pwfx->nChannels;
hr = m_pAudioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED,
  AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_NOPERSIST | AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_EVENTCALLBACK, 
  latency * 10000, 0, m_pwfx, NULL);
hr = m_pAudioClient->SetEventHandle(m_hCaptureEvent);
hr = m_pAudioClient->GetService(__uuidof(IAudioCaptureClient),
  (void**)&m_pCaptureClient);
```

And that's it.. Before calling this code I've started a worker thread that will listen to m_hCaptureEvent and call IAudioCaptureClient->GetBuffer(); whenever the capture event is triggered.

Of course using Microsoft.XNA.Audio.Microphone works fine to, but it's not always an option to reference the XNA framework.. :)

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply! I hope this helps people, but it's not my case. I did stop the audio, and anyway I could reproduce my problem even after restarting the device. I also tried running without debugging. In other words, my problem is consistent - it never works, not in any case.

Answer (score 1):

It was a really annoying problem which waste about 2 complete days of mine.My problem was solved by setting `AudioClientProperties.eCatagory` to `AudioCategory_Communications` instead of `AudioCategory_Other`.

After this long try and error period I am not sure that the problem won't repeat in the future because the API doesn't act very stable and every run may return a different result.

Edit:Yeah my guess was true.Restarting the wp emulator makes the buffer silent again.But changing the `AudioClientProperties.eCatagory` back to `AudioCategory_Other` again solve it.I still don't know what is wrong with it and what is the final solution.

Again I encounter the same problem and this time commenting (removing) the 
`properties.eCategory = AudioCategory_Communications;`
 solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can add my piece of advice for Windows Phone 8.1.
I made the following experiment.

1. Open capture device. Buffers are not silent.
2. Open render device with AudioDeviceRole::Communications. Buffers immediately go silent.
3. Close render device. Buffers are not silent.

Then I opened capture device with AudioDeviceRole::Communications and capture device works fine all the time.

For Windows 10 capture device works all the time, no matter if you open it with AudioDeviceRole::Communications or not.

Comment: I'm no longer working on this project (abandoned) but I do recall we were using Communications. I guess it's just a funny system bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. It seems like you can either use only `AudioCategory_Other` or create an instance of `VoipPhoneCall` and use only `AudioCategory_Communications`.

So the solution in my case was to use `AudioCategory_Communications` and create an outgoing `VoipPhoneCall`. You should implement the background agents as in [Chatterbox VoIP sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b) for the `VoipCallCoordinator` to work .