# Windows Phone 8, IAudioCaptureClient GetBuffer gets zero data in buffer returned

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing an app on WP8 use native audio. I use wasapi to capture and render client.
I initialized default device and I run GetService method to get IAudioCaptureClient. Then, I also set capture event handler. And in capture thread, I got event handler. I run GetBuffer method of IAudioCaptureClient. GetBuffer method returns 480 frames captured and also return a data buffer. But, data buffer only contains zero?? Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your project on windows phone emulator you should enable device microphone in WMAppManifest.xml - capabilities tab. 
Also you should release and close all the related objects and resources after finishing capture.Otherwise next time you'll receive empty buffer.

Also take a look at this:
[Captured audio buffers are all silent on Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796877/captured-audio-buffers-are-all-silent-on-windows-phone-8/19618947#19618947)